# Noise after changing the guitar jack socket

Tags: guitar, noise

I've recently changed the guitar socket. After I did it, I've been experiencing a lot of hum. The hum stops if I touch the metal part of the cable.If I touch the strings, the hum continues.
The socket seems perfectly solded! Does it has anything to do with the quality of the solder?

Best Regards

Comment: Is there any chance you switched the wires?

Comment: Well, "Seems soldered" and "Is soldered" are different things :-( .  Further, are you certain the previous socket didn't connect to earth ground via a fitting rather than a soldered wire?  It's pretty clear that either there's a faulty wire connection or the new jack is not making proper connection to the tip on your cable.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the internal wiring of the new socket (maybe the earthing of the circuit is damaged, not sure though). Get it repaired/replaced. However, try replacing the cables first (I insist spending a reasonable amount to get good ones this time).

Comment: You can switch polarity on some amps , lost a ground or you may need to swap the wires you soldered

Answer (score 4):

From the description it sounds like the ground side of the guitar's circuit is no longer connected at the output jack. Possibly the issue simply is that the bridge ground wire has become disconnected, which explains why the noise doesn't abate when the bridge is touched.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely to be about the quality of the solder, but might well be about the quality of the soldering.  Are you experienced in soldering?  It's easy to make a 'dry joint'.   Or left a wire off.  Or damaged something.

Take it to an expert. I'm sure you won't be charged much for a check-over.